# how to convert std::string to NSData and vice versa?

Tags: ios, c++11, cocos2d-x, google-play-games, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using google protocol buffer to send and receive data in cocos2d-x multiplayer game via Google Play Games Services iOS sdk.

Protocol buffer converts data to std::string but GPGS iOS sdk sends data via NSData hence I have to convert from std::string to NSData and then back to std::string after receiving data.

I am currently using following method:

(**std::string to NSData** and **NSData to std::string** will be done in different functions at different times. Following code just summarise what I am doing overall)

```
//PlayerData is protocol buffer class
PlayerData data, temp;

std::string dataStr;
data.SerializeToString(&dataStr);

NSString* nsDataStr = [NSString stringWithCString:dataStr.c_str()
                        encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

NSData* nsData = [nsDataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString* dataStr_2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsData
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

std::string foo = [dataStr_2 UTF8String];

temp.ParseFromString(foo);
```

**Initial string i.e dataStr after serializing**

"\r\x95n\x99D\x158\xddNDJ\nUmar SaeedR\x12p_CPH64oqq2K-TXxAB"

**size: 42**

**Final string i.e foo before parsing**

"\r\xc3\xafn\xc3\xb4D\x158\xe2\x80\xbaNDJ\nUmar SaeedR\x12p_CPH64oqq2K-TXxAB"

**size: 46**

the ParseFromString function of protocol buffer does not parse foo and returns false.

**How to do string conversions so that string remains same?**

Comment: Not sure if this happens automatically when creating std::string from c string (it should), but well worth considering: "UTF8String: This C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you use this property."

Comment: are nsDataStr and dataStr_2 identical or are they different already?

Comment: Sorry I don't really get what you are asking.

Comment: ok I get it now. nsDataStr and dataStr are identical. I think the problem is in conversion between std::string to NSString and vice versa

Comment: nsDataStr=@"\rïnùX›NDJ\nUmar SaeedRp_CPH64oqq2K-TXxAB" dataStr_2=@"\rïnùX›NDJ\nUmar SaeedRp_CPH64oqq2K-TXxAB"

Comment: If you haven't yet solved this, you may want to specify a character set (like UTF-8) in order to make String encoding and decoding more consistent.  Take a look at the [TBMP Skeleton Sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/ios-basic-samples/blob/master/TBMPSkeleton/TBMPSkeleton/GameData.m) for an example of this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::string str = "123";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:str.data() length:str.length()];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but... Could you use protobufs ParseFromArray instead of ParseFromString?

IE

```
const void *bytes = [parseData bytes];
int byteLen = (int)[parseData length];

protobufMessage.ParseFromArray(bytes, byteLen);
```

Just a thought.